# How to disable the generating of synthetic view properties by the Kotlin Android extensions plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

The Kotlin Android Extensions plugin generates static properties for each view with an ID from my app layout files, as it is described in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding).

I would like to disable this feature, because we use DataBinding instead of the Kotlin synthetic view properties, and sometimes I import them by accident; also it adds extra build overhead for something we don't use.

Disabling the Android extensions plugin is not possible, because we use the Parcelize feature which is done by the same plugin.

Comment: For the importing by accident issue, one mitigation is to edit your Android Studio settings in Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import, and add to the excluded packages list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nowadays, android-extensions plugin is [discontinued](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html) so the best solution will be to just remove this plugin by removing `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` from your `build.gradle`.

Instead of synthetics we should use [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

As explained in the first link, if you're also using parcelizer, you just need to change `android-extensions` plugin to `kotlin-parcelize` and change the import statement `import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` for `import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize` wherever is needed.

More info to migrate from android-extensions to JetPack [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).

Answer (score 24):

There is a `features` property in the `androidExtensions` DSL that allows you to provide a list of features to enable. Currently, there is only two available, `parcelize` and `views`. To disable synthetic view properties, add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
   // ...
}

androidExtensions {
    features = ["parcelize"]
}
```

Source: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/6bef27e1e889b17ae84dd2ff99881727f13ac3e5/plugins/android-extensions/android-extensions-compiler/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/android/synthetic/AndroidComponentRegistrar.kt#L57

Comment: Thanks, this works almost fully, my only problem is that it still generates the synthetic classes. But if you try to compile the app, it fails.

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me, on Android Studio 3.4. References to the synthetic objects still compile and function.

Comment: This works for me on Android Studio 3.5.3. Note that `androidExtensions` is a top-level closure, meaning it goes outside of the `android` closure.

Comment: This does not work for me on Android Studio 4.0 Beta 5, even as a top level closure.  It's still generating the synthetic properties

Comment: @kyhule what if we don't use parcelize either? Would `features = []` suffice?

Comment: @coltonidle That was my case, I just removed the whole `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` line, it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't have that plugin at all.

Comment: I tried the same on android studio 4.0.1 and it does work. It seems in editor we can see the Kotlin synthetics but when I run the code it gives error "Unresolved reference: synthetic". At least no one in the team will be able to use it by mistake.